# silverlight website through visual basic.net

Tags: vb.net, silverlight

I want to know, any way to call a website url built by silverlight from my vb.net program depending on a value entered through my software?

To be more specific, the url that I want to call is http://lakein.mygisonline.com and I want to write the search for parcel through my application (e.g 45-15-36-362-008.000-041) instead writing it on the main website, then I need it to open the page depending on this criteria.

Comment: Have you explored the WebBrowser control?

Comment: the issue that search on the website which is built by silverlight can't add the search criteria with the URL, so I don't know how to call it.

Comment: Is this a public site or do you have control of the source code?

Comment: this is a public site, I want the user to open it through my software and add the search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The website is created by The Sidwell Company and they have documentation here:

http://www.sidwellco.com/gis-software-products/software-support/

I'd go explore it and see if they have a developer API available.

It's possible you'll be able to pass the parcel id as part of the URL.